# How to find all words with 3 same, consecutive letters with RegEx?

Tags: regex

I have a text, lets say:

> Ich gehe auf die Donau und mache eine tolle Schifffahrt während ich Nussschalen esse.

So now, I want to find all words with 3 same, consecutive letters in it. In my case this would be:

> Schifffahrt

And

> Nussschale

I don't have a lot of experience in RegEx, so I would really appreciate help. I opened a [regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/oA4sG6/1) for you.

Thank you really much. (For those who want to know why I need something strange: FOr some reason I like this words with 3 same letter in it because they are rare. So I thouhgt I program a bot which is requesting Websites, reading the content, and saves and outputs all found words with 3 same letters in it. Nice, isn't it? :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b\w*(\w)\1\1\w*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG4qS6/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b    # word boundary
\w*   # match 0 more word chars
\w    # match a word char and capture it as group #1
\1\1  # match 2 more instances of group #1
\w*   # match 0 more word chars
```

Comment: You don't need the trailing `\b` - it's implied by the preceding greedy `\w*`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the leading `\b` either, for similar reasons

Comment: Maybe add some text for why you don't need `\b` - it's an interesting point

Comment: @Bohemian You're being _greedy_ now :P

Comment: @Bohemian With the leading word boundary regex101 shows 422 steps, without 759 steps in the sample demo.

Comment: @bobble good point. that makes sense too; the leading word boundary stops unnecessary attempts to match that start mid-word

Comment: Good point @bobblebubble, due to that reason I rolled back my change and reverted back to previous version with starting `\b`